# Cannot write to Elasticsearch with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

The elasticsearch server exists at a linux server with version 5.4.1.

The spark cluster used is spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.
I added `spark.jars.packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:5.4.1` to spark-defaults.conf
Starting the master and slave is successfull and the spark webui can be reached at localhost:8080.
Was started with `./start-master.sh`  and `./start-slave.sh spark://ApacheFlink:7077`

I use Intellij IDEA and sbt.
scala version used is 2.11.8

Here is the scala code.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.elasticsearch.spark._

object TestInput {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
println("Hello, world")

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestInput").setMaster("spark://ApacheFlink:7077")
conf.set("es.nodes","elasticserver")
conf.set("es.port","9200")
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val numbers = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
val airports = Map("arrival" -> "Otopeni", "SFO" -> "San Fran")

sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports)).saveToEs("test/TestInput")
}
}
```

I played around with the sbt dependencies a lot. These are my findings until now.

All my tries use `scalaVersion := 2.11.8`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided"

 [error] /home/foo/Desktop/AnotherOne/src/main/scala/TestInput.scala:4: object elasticsearch is not a member of package org
    [error] import org.elasticsearch.spark._
    [error]            ^
    [error] /home/foo/Desktop/AnotherOne/src/main/scala/TestInput.scala:20: value saveToEs is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]]
    [error]     sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports)).saveToEs("test/TestInput")
    [error]                                        ^
    [error] two errors found
    [error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

2nd try:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % "5.4.1"

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:55)
    at TestInput$.main(TestInput.scala:11)
    at TestInput.main(TestInput.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

3rd try;

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % "5.4.1"

17/08/09 13:43:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 192.168.1.111, executor 0): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I even tried importing elasticseach-hadoop with other error messages.
My question now is pretty simple. 
What am I doing wrong? I currently have no more ideas.
Is my spark cluster missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You *may* have a conflict between the spark jars that come as dependencies of the elasticsearch-spark module, and from your build.sbt.

I got it working this way, in my build.sbt :

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1" % "compile",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1" % "compile",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.1" % "compile",

    "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "5.0.2" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.spark")
)
```

Comment: When i try your imports a get this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf`

Comment: Everything runs fine if I run the code from within the spark shell located at spar-2-2-0-bin-hadoop2.7. only problems seems to be intellij sbt execution

Comment: did you have to download hadoop, point to anything hadoop related in any config file? @GPI

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by my release and my dev config files ! The "provided" for Spark should, of course, be "compile". I'll edit in a second